# Where does the idea of chosenness and particularly the phrase "Light unto the nations" originate?

Tags: sources-mekorot

Is it falsely attributed to Judaism? Is it really Jewish? Is it found in the Pentateuch? Talmud? Post-Talmudic? Are there certain branches of Judaism that don’t accept these doctrines?

By the way, I don’t really know what would be the appropriate tags for this question, so please feel free to improve the entire post including the tags as you might see fit.

Comment: The idea of chosenness goes back to G-d's covenant with Abraham and is referenced many times throughout the Torah, especially in Deuteronomy. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jews_as_the_chosen_people#In_the_Bible) are just a few of them. The specific term "light unto the nations" comes from [Isaiah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_unto_the_nations#Origin).

Answer (score 3):

> כי עם קדוש אתה לה' אלקיך **ובך בחר ה'** להיות לו לעם סגלה מכל העמים
> אשר על־פני האדמה
>
> For you are a holy people to Hashem your God, and **Hashem has chosen
> you** to be a special possession to Himself, out of all the nations
> that are upon the earth. [Devarim 14:2]
>
> ויאמר נקל מהיותך לי עבד להקים את־שבטי יעקב (ונצירי) [ונצורי] ישראל
> להשיב ונתתיך **לאור גוים** להיות ישועתי עד־קצה הארץ
>
> And He
> said, "It is too light a thing to be my servant to raise up the tribes
> of Yaacov, and to restore the preserved of Yisrael: I will also make
> you **a light to the nations**, that my salvation may be to the end of
> the earth. [Yishayahu 49:6]

Answer (score -9):

The concept of a chosen people is found in the Torah. However, there is another concept that I think we should recognize. We need to respect everyone and recognize that everyone is chosen.

God himself says to the prophet Amos in 9:7:

> “Are you not like the children of the Ethiopians to Me, O children of
> Israel? Have I not brought up Israel out of the land of Egypt, and the
> Philistines from Caphtor, and Aram from Kir?”

Maimonides rejects the notion of chosen people. Maimonides' God lacks conscious will and such a deistic God cannot choose Jews or anyone else, and cannot choose at all.

Spinoza writes that "every nation is on a par with the rest, and God has not in these respects chosen one people rather than another."

Albert Einstein, the smartest man who ever lived, said Jews were not the chosen people and "have no different quality for me than all other people... I cannot perceive anything “chosen” about them."

Here we are. I have quoted three of Judaism's intellectuals, Maimonides, Spinoza, and Einstein, and God himself.

Thus, it is falsely attributed to Judaism that Jews think they are the chosen people.

Comment: "Maimonides' God lacks conscious will and such a deistic God cannot choose Jews or anyone else, and cannot choose at all."

Huh?

Comment: "Spinoza writes" - Spinoza's philosophy was trash (he literally collapsed into pantheism because he didn't know how to properly deal with modal collapse and other related topics) and he was literally excommunicated and branded as a heretic, I don't know why he's being quoted here. Same with Einstein, the guy was an atheist and not particularly knowledgable about religion and philosophy itself.

Comment: @setszu excommunicated by whom or from what? But yeah, I agree with you. DV’d this answer.

Comment: @Seekinganswers Just google "excomunnication of Spinoza"

Comment: @setszu Maimonides' God is impersonal like the sun. And Einstein said, "I am not an atheist." He believed in a God. He believed in Spinoza's God. And Spinoza believed in a God. His God did not get involved in our lives. By the way, I do not think Spinoza was a pantheist. And in the talmudic tradition, there is no such thing as theological heresy.

Comment: @setszu I quote Spinoza frequently because I agree with him. Spinoza was a rationalist and he was one of the greatest Jewish thinkers who ever lived, in the same league with Maimonides and Einstein.

Comment: @TurkHill lol..

Comment: @TurkHill The only partially redeemable thing about Spinoza was possibly his epistemology but that's about it, and even then, his PSR work is kinda meh. Also you're wrong about Spinoza and if this is what they believed, then they were provably wrong again, etc.

Comment: Your insatiable love for buzzwords never fails to amuse me, Turk hill

Comment: @TurkHill What's the book? And still, even if they wrote a book, it doesn't change the fact that it disagrees with the authoritative sources, both Jewish and secular, that we are to follow.

Comment: @setszu https://www.amazon.com/Authentic-King-Solomon-Israel-Drazin/dp/9652299332

Comment: @TurkHill Thanks

Comment: "Maimonides rejects the notion of chosen people." This is simply not true (see H. Tefillah 7:10). Your other sources (Spinoza, Einstein) are irrelevant as they are not sources of Judaism.

Comment: @Deuteronomy 1. Maimonides' law code is
intended for the
unlearned masses. 2. the passage
that you cite here from
the laws of prayer in his
law code, Maimonides is
merely quoting the
blessings that are recited
in relation to the
commandment of the
study of Torah. 3. Maimonides significantly
omits any notion of
chosen people from the
Guide of the Perplexed. 4. Maimonides
omits the notion of
chosen people from his
"13 Principles of Faith"
and, this is especially
striking.

Comment: @Deuteronomy 5. Maimonides loves the
number 14. There are 14
chapters to his Dictionary
of Logic, 14 principles in
his introduction to his
Book of Commandments,
14 books comprising his
law code and 14 sections
in the material that he
presents in the 3rd part of
the Guide relating to the
subject of reasons for the
commandments. But,
there are strangely only
13 principles of his "13
Principles of Faith"!

Comment: @Deuteronomy In my opinion, the 14th
missing principle is the
notion of chosen people.

Comment: @TurkHill In the Maimonidean tradition the law is intended for all Jews, not merely the "unlearned masses." However the unlearned masses serve to benefit the most as one of the functions of the law is the cultivation of true opinion. Maimonides would not include in his restatement of the law something that he would have thought cultivated false opinion. As for not including the election of Israel in the Iqarim - there is no need to include it as the notion is already covered in the 6th iqar (belief in the words of the prophets).

Comment: @Deuteronomy Maimonides disparages halacha, Jewish law. Halacha, in Maimonides' conception, was only for the unlearned masses. the fact that Rambam omitted the election of Israel in the Iqarim is proof that he did not take the concept of the chosen people seriously. To quote a genius on the matter: Jews were not the chosen people and "have no different quality for me than all other people... I cannot perceive anything “chosen” about them." Albert Einstein

Comment: @TurkHill at this point you have simply repeated yourself, and without furnishing any evidence of your claims. Take care.

Comment: @Deuteronomy I'd rather listen to a genius: Jews "have no different quality for me than all other people." Einstein

Comment: @Deuteronomy Spinoza said that "every nation is on a par with the rest, and God has not in these respects chosen one people rather than another."

Comment: @TurkHill you are free to listen to whomever you'd like but you are again repeating yourself. Citing the same non-Jewish sources ad nauseum does not make it any more true. Einstein and Spinoza are not voices of Judaism.

Comment: @Deuteronomy Non-Jewish? Do you deny that Einstein and Spinoza were Jewish? They were Jewish by virtue of being born of a Jewish mother. Spinoza was excommunicated but he himself never left Judaism. He never converted to Christianity. Spinoza is the strongest voice for Judaism.

Comment: Again, they are not voices of Judaism. No more so than Karl Marx, Noam Chomsky, Stan Lee, or Woody Allen are voices of Judaism. Being a Jew by ethnicity does not mean that anything the person says is representative of Judaism. It is representative of their own particular views.

Comment: @Deuteronomy We agree that Einstein voiced his own particular views however, I am convinced that Spinoza never left Judaism. I think we could say that he represents a minority view. Spinoza should be welcomed back. He was very pious and deeply religious Jew. He was not an atheist. He believed in God. His excommunication should be lifted.

Comment: @TurkHill his herem never was lifted, as he was unrepentant. Had there been reason to lift the herem in his lifetime, the hakhamim of his community would have done so. He rejected fundamental tenets of Judaism and his views were indeed his own - not those of Judaism. So you have neither demonstrated the Rambam rejected the election of Israel, nor have you cited any Jewish source that does. Your entire response is without merit. You are simply repeating yourself over and over.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149970/discussion-between-turk-hill-and-deuteronomy).

Comment: @Deuteronomy His views were entirely his own - he never left the Jewish community and what he wrote was his understanding of what the Bible was truly teaching. Spinoza taught what he felt scripture was teaching. He never converted to Christianity shows that he still identified as a Jew. His views should be adopted and not neglected. Thus in my book he counts as a possible source for a Jewish view on the election of Israel.

Comment: @Deuteronomy The quote by Spinoza (above) was his attempt or commentary to explain what the Bible was teaching. It should represent a minority view within the Jewish tradition.

Comment: It is not a minority position. It as an external position. It is not a part of the corpus of Judaism and its texts.

Comment: @Deuteronomy I disagree. It is a minority position and, part of the corpus of Judaism. In fact, arguably, Spinoza was a closet-Maimonidean. The views Spinoza espouses are directly linked to the bible. How can they be outside of Judaism when their source is Judaism?

Comment: @TurkHill claiming that Spinoza is a part of the corpus of Judaism is like claiming Paul the Apostle is a part of the corpus of Judaism. He also attempted to link his views to the Hebrew bible. Just because someone is Jewish and comments on Jewish texts, does not make their views or comments a part of Judaism.

Comment: @Deuteronomy Actually, the first Christians were Jews, early Christianity was a sect of Judaism. Paul went off and invented Christianity. Spinoza never made a new religion nor converted to Christianity. He never stopped identifying as a Jew. Even Paul had some good points.

Comment: @Deuteronomy What Paul says is true, accept it. What he says is false, reject it. Unlike Paul, Spinoza never invented a new religion.

Comment: You are suggesting that the goalposts be shifted. This conversation is not about what is "true" and whether someone started a new religion.

Comment: @Deuteronomy Spinoza is for me a reliable source of Jewish opinion. Why are you so hostile to Spinoza?

Comment: @TurkHill then unfortunately you do not understand what constitutes a source **within** Judaism. All the best bud.